# Is there an efficient way to collect items using Thaumcraft Golems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I was wondering if there was a way to automatically collect the items harvested by Straw Golems in the Thaumcraft mod for Minecraft, or do you need to always pick up after them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use Wood Golems.(Also from Thaumcraft) Place them on a chest you want them to put the stuff in and they will collect for you.

Comment: You have to use the Gather Golem Core and use it on any Golem. You might also need to use the golemnacers bell.

Comment: @Aaron128l that depends on which mod version they're running. One of the older ones had different material golems for different jobs.